# Python CSV Add Numbers to Empty Cells

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Python 3.8. I've a CSV file with 12,000 rows and 4 columns. One column has over 4000 blank cells in various places. Starting at the top, I need to place a sequential number in each blank cell starting at 1.

**Existing**:

```
First,Sec,Third,Fourth
R,E,C,D
S,F,C,D
blank,S,C,D
V,G,C,D
blank,Q,C,D
blank,F,C,D
E,W,C,D
```

**Proposed**:

```
First,Sec,Third,Fourth
R,E,C,D
S,F,C,D
1,S,C,D
V,G,C,D
2,L,C,D
3,F,C,D
E,W,C,D
```

I'm a bit of novice but this where I got to. Thank you in advance.

```
import csv
 
with open('Original.csv', newline='') as DataIn2:
        fileReader2 = csv.reader(DataIn2)

Start_Number = 0
Number_Fill = Start_Number + 1

if (fileReader2['Data ID'].isnull().Number_Fill
else next(row) ???

with open('New.csv', 'w', newline='') as DataOut2:
    fileWriter2 = csv.writer(DataOut2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its easier to use pandas and process the df then you can save the processed df:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Original.csv')

Start_Number = 1
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    if pd.isnull(row['Data ID']):
        df.loc[i,'Data ID'] = Start_Number;
        Start_Number +=1

df.to_csv('New.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for your help. This worked exactly how I needed it.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, reading your code I imagine that you want each line of your csv to be a dictionary, then you should use `fileReader2 = csv.DictReader(CrimeDataIn2)`.

Second, since you are new to Python start by converting your csv reader into a list so you can understand how to deal with it

```
reader = list(fileReader2)
```

reader will be a list of dictionaries and you can iterate over it with a for loop:

```
for row in reader:
```

then you want to verify, for each row if the `row['Crime ID']` is blank. If it is, you substitute to your Number_Fill and add 1 to Number_Fill. You don't need an else statement.

Be aware that using pandas may be easier than using csv

Answer (score 0):

If using `pandas` is an option, given the test data, you could try the following,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('PSNIstreetCrimeMapDataRefined_Test.csv',delimiter=',')
df['First'] = df['First'].fillna(df['First'].isnull().cumsum())
```

**Output**:

```
>>> df
  First Sec Third Fourth
0     R   E     C      D
1     S   F     C      D
2     1   S     C      D
3     V   G     C      D
4     2   Q     C      D
5     3   F     C      D
6     E   W     C      D
```

pandas reads blank files as `NaNs`, I am filling `NaN` values with cumulative sum of `NaN` values. You can save the output `csv` as the following:

```
df.to_csv('PSNIstreetCrimeMapDataRefinedAgain_Test.csv',index=False)
```

**A more general approach**:

If one or more columns have `blank` lines(i.e. `NaN` values). For example:

```
>>> df
  First  Sec Third Fourth
0     R    E     C      D
1     S  NaN     C      D
2   NaN    S     C      D
3     V    G     C      D
4   NaN    Q     C      D
5   NaN  NaN     C      D
6     E    W     C      D
```

We can utilize the `apply` method together with the solution above:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x : x.fillna(x.isnull().cumsum()))
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  First Sec Third Fourth
0     R   E     C      D
1     S   1     C      D
2     1   S     C      D
3     V   G     C      D
4     2   Q     C      D
5     3   2     C      D
6     E   W     C      D
```

Comment: Does this work for you? Can you please try and let me know? if it does, please consider upvoting